# Laravel URL facade temporarySignedRoute to external url

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 8 to generate a temporary signed route and pass some params, but I'd like my URL to take me to some URL of my choosing rather than a page in my project.

For context, my Laravel 8 project is an API, so there are no views, my API is then consumed by a front-end project written in Nuxt.

I've tried adding my URL to the first arg of `temporarySignedRoute` but it says that my route isn't found.

```php
$verifyURL = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
  'https://example.com/account/verify', Carbon::now()->addHours(24), ['contact' => 5, 'team' => 'john']
);
```

What am I missing or what workaround is there here?

#### UPDATE

So it turns out that I don't need to take the user to an external URL, but it seems that the wrong URL is being generated by `URL::temporarySignedRoute`.

The start of my generated URL is (for example) https://example.com/api/contact/verify and I need the URL to be https://api.example.com/api/contact/verify

So the same domain, except a sub-domain.

It looks like the `APP_URL` isn't being read because I changed it and it has no impact, and besides, this is used elsewhere, so I tried updating the URL with:

```php
$verifyURL = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
  'contact.verify', Carbon::now()->addHours(24), ['contact' => 5, 'team' => 'john]
);

// fix for wrong URL
$verifyURL = str_replace('example.com', 'api.example.com', $verifyURL);
```

However, this appears to have an invalid signature when the link provided by `$verifyURL` is clicked? How can I get the `api` part at the beginning?

Comment: Is the controller there to catch the url you have just generated? I might be wrong but the url should be limited to your domain or the domain laravel catches

Comment: `temporarySignedRoute` only accepts route name, not url https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.html#method_temporarySignedRoute. You can just copy the signature generation logic from the source. It's actually just a normal SHA-256 HMAC https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L338

Comment: Is there not a way for me to add a `Route::redirect('/verify', 'https://example.com/')` and then point the `temporarySignedRoute` to `verify` which would then redirect with params? Because I tried this and id didn't redirect, unless I'm mistaken

Comment: @YohanesGultom I've updated my description with some findings, I don't need to go to an external URL, but rather a sub-domain of my current URL. Why doesn't a `str_replace` work here

Comment: Do both websites (example.com & api.example.com) share same APP_KEY? If no, I don't think any of them can verify signature generated by other

Comment: My Laravel project is an API, my front-end is a Nuxt JS project that communicates with the API with requests. `APP_KEY` is generated on the API, but they are both on the same server

Comment: @RyanH any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

URL::temporarySignedRoute() has a fourth parameter called $absolute which is a boolean. So if you want to prepend a custom url rather than the default url used by Laravel, this is the variable to change.

The default value for $absolute is true. Therefore in order to prepend your own custom url, be sure to change it to false first as below:

```
$verifyURL = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
  'contact.verify', Carbon::now()->addHours(24), ['contact' => 5, 'team' => 'john], false // The $absolute value
);
```

Then concatenate your custom url:

```
$your_custom_url . $verifyURL;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Doing this, you wont be able to verify your signed route (when the user clicks it) is there a way to solve that without overriding the default Laravel code?

Answer (score 0):

First step, in the `AppServiceProvider` boot method, you need to register custom URL signing:

```php
    public function boot()
    {
        // This allows us to generate a temporary url for report downloading
        Storage::disk('reports')->buildTemporaryUrlsUsing(function ($path, $expiration, $options) {
            return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
                'report.download',
                $expiration,
                array_merge($options, ['path' => $path])
            );
        });
    }
```

To create the URL:

```
Storage::disk('reports')->temporaryUrl($pathname, Carbon::now()->addSeconds(10))
```

To download the file, this is my controller:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Storage;
use URL;

class ReportDownloadController extends Controller
{
    public function download(Request $request)
    {
        if (!URL::signatureHasNotExpired($request)) {
            return response('The URL has expired.');
        }

        if (!URL::hasCorrectSignature($request)) {
            return response('Invalid URL provided');
        }

        return Storage::disk('reports')->download($request->get('path'));
    }
}
```